# Flutter, hot not to call StreamBuilder when setState

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

My screen has an AnimatedBackground which is continuously keep looping like this

```
Stack(
 children: [
  AnimatedContainer(
       duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          onEnd: () {
              setState(() {

                 //doing some animation repeatedly

                  });
                },
               ),
              StreamBuilder(
                   //keeping rebuild because of the above setState
              ),
         ],
    ),
```

I am so stuck right now rebuild is so often, because of the setState() (the problem)

I want to use StreamBuilder inside this screen because the information is continuously changing

how not to loop StreamBuilder? how to achieve this?

Comment: StreamBuilder is supposed to react on stream(s) events. It basically just another Flutter's widget. If you need loop use something like while (true) { if (interrupt) {break;} else { doSomething() } }

Comment: @Alex.Marynovskyi I\`m sorry I didn\`t get it could you explain more detaily? I do not want it to loop, I want it to be only reacting from Stream Events

Comment: If you just want it to react to events from stream then remove setState({}). It's not needed if you have StreamBuilder. You just receive new data from stream event inside StreamBuilder and return new widgets or widgets with new data inside StreamBuilder's builder function.

Comment: @Alex.Marynovskyi I know that but I need the setState because of the animation background

Comment: So, you need both and you don't want to rerun StreamBuilder on every setState update, right?

Comment: @Alex.Marynovskyi Yes Yes exactly that is what I want my friend

Comment: I misunderstood you from the beginning, sorry) Since setState({}) updates the whole widgets where you call it, you need to somehow separate your widgets. The idea is that the widget where you call setState should be lower in the widget's tree, so it won't trigger widget with StreamBuilder to rerun.

Comment: @Alex.Marynovskyi wow it would be difficult. thanks for advice bro I will refer that

Comment: @Alex.Marynovskyi I tried as you said and I think I figured out. please answer this question so I adopt it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since setState({}) method updates the whole widget where you call it, you need in some way separate your widgets. The idea is that the widget where you call setState method should be lower in the widget's tree and the widget, which contains StreamBuilder is upper. As a result calling setState method won't trigger widget with StreamBuilder to rerun.

Comment: I have tried your idea where to put the setstate below in the widgets tree and the StreamBuilder to be higher then setstate. But it dosen't seem to work please refer to my question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76982878/streambuilder-always-getting-new-data-when-using-setstate-flutter]