# Streambuilder always getting new data when using setstate flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have a StreamBuilder and an int To increment number to do that I use setState function. And the problem is the StreamBuilder always getting new data every time setState is accur is there anyway to make the StreamBuilder not affect by setState every time the setState accur. To summarise is that **Stop StreamBuilder from getting new data from backend every time when using setstate**

**full code**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StreamBuildTest2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const StreamBuildTest2({super.key});

  @override
  State<StreamBuildTest2> createState() => _StreamBuildTest2State();
}

class _StreamBuildTest2State extends State<StreamBuildTest2> {
  String userUid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  //Variable to increment number
  int number = 0;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //The StreamBuilder that’s getting new data every time setState accur 
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(userUid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //Data from firebase backend
          var fullName = snapshot.data?.get('fullName');
          var email = snapshot.data?.get('email');
          var profileUrl = snapshot.data?.get('profileUrl');
          //
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Container();
          }
          return Column(
            children: [
              //To get user profile
              FutureBuilder(
                future: downloadURL(profileUrl),
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                      snapshot.hasData) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      height: 110,
                      width: 110,
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
               //The user profile always getting new data every time setState accur
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!),
                          radius: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
                      snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Container();
                  }
                  return Container();
                },
              ),
              Text(fullName),
              Text(email),
              Text(number.toString()),
             //Here’s the setState
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  number += 1;
                }),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Text('SetState Button'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
 //Doesn’t matter here
  Future<String> downloadURL(String file) async {
    try {
      String downloadURL =
          await storage.ref('usersProfile/$file').getDownloadURL();
      print(downloadURL);
      return downloadURL;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return downloadURL(file);
  }
}
```

**feel free to Modified my code**

**Problem**

The offsetNotifier can change but when I use `onPanUpdate: _offsetNotifier,` I don’t want the FutureBuilder to change as well

```
final ValueNotifier<Offset> offsetNotifier = ValueNotifier(const Offset(0, 0));

void _offsetNotifier(DragUpdateDetails details) => offsetNotifier.value += details.delta;

   ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: offsetNotifier,
           builder: (_, value, __) {
              return Positioned(
                  left: offsetNotifier.value.dx,
                  top: offsetNotifier.value.dy,
                        child: FutureBuilder(
                            future: downloadURL(profileUrl),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
                                return CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!),
                                  radius: 10.0,
                                );
                              }
                              return Container();
                            }),
                      );
                    }),

 Future<String> downloadURL(String file) async {
    try {
      String downloadURL =
          await storage.ref('widgetsProfile/$file').getDownloadURL();
      print(downloadURL);
      return downloadURL;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return downloadURL(file);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use ValueNotifier and ValueListenableBuilder to avoid rebuilding your entire widget to a _counter notifier, you can try that dartpad example

https://dartpad.dev/?id=1e52b13f6a9727e541baa74b58b1b558

```dart
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ValueNotifier<int> _counterNotifier = ValueNotifier(0);

  void _increment() => _counterNotifier.value = _counterNotifier.value + 1;
  void _decrement() => _counterNotifier.value = _counterNotifier.value - 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint('this does not re-render');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: _decrement,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 48,
                  child: Center(
                  child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: _counterNotifier,
                    builder: (_, count, __) {
                      return Text(
                        '$count',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                   ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: _increment,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked beautify regarding to my situation that is trying to increment or  decrement num.  But many popular problems for everybody is setState if you can give me an idea to this trouble it would be lovely **example**   `String? loading = 'no';  onTap:  () => setState(() {
                  loading = 'yes';
                }),`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm glad the answer helped you. this method works for every value you want to update. Simply provide the type, record, or even data structure and you can modify and listen to one or multiple widgets within your tree. 
For the loading, it's recommended to use a boolean instead of a string.
```dart
ValueNotifier<bool> isLoadingNotifier = ValueNotifier(false);
and the  ValueListenableBuilder(valueListenable: isLoadingNotifier, builder: ...)
```

Be aware streams already have built-in methods to detect loading state so you might want to look into that too.

Comment: Sorry I got one more problem your method is working find and all but what If I wrap ValueListenableBuilder with position widget and there’s a FutureBuilder inside the position widget as well. So every time I change the offsetNotifier.value.dx and offsetNotifier.value.dy the FutureBuilder will always get downloadUrl. I don’t want that to happen. How to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: You can see the code that I just add in the Problem section.

Comment: ValueListenableBuilder will rebuild everything in its builder return method. so you're back to the first problem. Instead, you can move the code within the child property of the widget and then return that same child using the provided param.

in your particular case, you can use the cached_network_image package instead of the FutureBuilder so it won't re-fetch the image again.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the Firestore API call in the `build` method of your widget, it gets executed each time the widget gets (re)rendered. While this works, it is indeed wasteful.

So what you'll want to do instead is:

1. Call the Firestore API once from the [`initState` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) of your widget.
2. Put the `Stream` you get back from the `snapshots()` call there, into the state.
3. Then use the stream from the state in your `build` method.

Randal Schwartz also recorded a great video explaining, so I recommend checking that out: [Fixing a common FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder problem](https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg)